# How do use putStrLn for tracing (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, monads, unsafe-perform-io

I am trying to get a Haskell function to show whenever it is applied by adding a call to "putStrLn":

```
isPrime2 1 = False

isPrime2 n = do
    putStrLn n
    null (filter (==0) (map (mod n) (filter isPrime2 [2..(floor (sqrt(fromIntegral (n-1))))])))
```

(The ultimate goal is to demonstrate why one version of isPrime is more efficient than another.)

When I load the above code into GHCi, I get the error:

> Couldn't match expected type `Bool` with actual type `m0 b0`

I'm sure this is a n00b mistake.  Could someone tell me the right way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why are you subtracting 1 from `n` before taking its square root?  That will only work for numbers that aren't squares of primes and will fail for, e.g., 25.

Comment: @jwodder, thanks for the correct to the primes algorithm.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is, that Haskell has a strict distinction between *pure* functions such as `(+)` and `map` and *impure* actions such as `putStrLn` and `main`. A pure function is supposed to always yield the same result when given the same input and not modifying anything. This obviously prohibits uses of `PutStr` and friends. The type system actually enforces this separation. Each function that does IO or is impure in any way has an `IO` sticking in front of it's type.

---

tl;dr; use `trace` from the module `Debug.Trace`:

```
import Debug.Trace

isPrime2 1 = False
isPrime2 n = show n `trace` null (filter (==0) (map (mod n) (filter isPrime2 [2..(floor (sqrt(fromIntegral (n-1))))])))
```

But beware that the results may be rather surprising as there is no guarantee that your code will actually run; the argument of trace may run once or twice or any other number of times.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you have these kinds of type errors like `Couldn't match expected type X with actual type Y` you should use the haskell type system to guide you.
So let's see what is the problem:

You have a pure function with the type `Int -> Bool`. And you want to print some debug output which is clearly *not pure* (i.e. which lives in the **IO Monad**).
But anyway what you want to write is s.th. along those lines:

```
foo x 
  | x > 0 = debug "ok" True
  | otherwise = debug "ohhh...no" False
```

Still, the type of your function should be `foo :: Int -> Bool`

So let's define a `debug` function that will satisfy the type-checker. It would have to take a String (your debug message) and a Bool (your result) and only evaluate to the Bool.

```
debug :: String -> Bool -> Bool
debug = undefined
```

But if we try to implement it, it kind of does not work since we can't escape the IO Monad since the type of putStrLn is `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`. In order to combine it with evaluating to a `Bool` we will have to put the `Bool` in the context of the `IO` too:

```
debugIO msg result = putStrLn msg >> return result
```

Ok, let's ask ghci for the type of this function:

```
Main> :t debugIO
debugIO :: String -> b -> IO b
```

So we get an `IO Bool` but would need just a `Bool`.
Is there a function with the type `IO b -> b`? A quick lookup on [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=IO+b+-%3E+b) gives us a hint:

The infamous `unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a` has the type we need here.
So now we *could* implement our `debug` function in terms of `debugIO`:

```
debug :: String -> Bool -> Bool
debug s r = unsafePerformIO $ debugIO s r
```

which actually is pretty much what you get with the `trace` function in the [`Debug.Trace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Debug-Trace.html#g:1) package as already pointed out by FUZxxl.
And since we agree that *one should never use* `unsafePerformIO` the usage of the `trace` function is preferred. Just keep in mind that despite it's pure type signature it actually is also **not** referential transparent and uses `unsafePerformIO` underneath.

Comment: Please note, that you should **never** use the function `unsafePerformIO`. There is nearly *always* a better solution. This function is evil; it allows you to do things that are otherwise impossible and to destroy some safety assumptions the compiler could make otherwise. If you use `unsafePerformIO`, think twice and if you are not 100% sure, *don't use it*! There are some legitimate use cases, like `trace`, but they are rare.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I'm well aware of the merits and dangers of `unsafePerformIO`. But in order to implement what espertus was asking for I don't see any other option. As you pointed out, `trace` _is_ in fact implemented in terms of `unsafePerformIO`. I'd say it falls into the same category of code that should usually be treated with a long stick.

Comment: And would you also say that you should never use `trace`, except for debugging? For example, you should never use it to print information that users are supposed to read when the code is in production?

Comment: @MatrixFrog: exactly. `trace` should only be used for quick and dirty debugging. (with an emphasis on _dirty_). In situations where you are dealing with user visible output you most probably already have to run some code in the IO Monad. The `trace` function is, like `unsafePerformIO`, not referentially transparent. You might not always see your user messages as you would expect them.

Comment: If you just enter the type of your `debug` function into Hoogle, you get `trace` as the first hit, so you could have stopped there instead of introducing `unsafePerformIO` (the function whose name must never be spoken!)

Comment: @oliver Can I add a small remark that one should never ever use The Function That Must Not Be Named?

Comment: @FUZxxl sure. Programming haskell you should never use it. In the case of library writers I'm actually not quite sure...afaict there are usecases where it makes sense. But I'll add your remark to make that more clear.